# Unsigned ipa crashes on launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, jailbreak, unsigned, ipa

I followed this tutorial ([Generating an unsigned IPA iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396299/generating-an-unsigned-ipa-ios-application)) for an application I created. I installed it onto my iphone5s with ifunbox. The problem is when it goes to launch it shows the new launch screen with Xcode 6, where it says the app and that it's copywrited and stuff, and them immediately crashes. In the iOS simulator it runs perfectly. I don't know if I'm missing a step or what. Thanks in advance.

I'm running iOS 8.1, built with Xcode 6, installed on a jailbroken iPhone 5s, written with objective-c on Yosemite. Incase that information helps.

Comment: This question is about programming.  App signing is a programming task.  Stop with the silly close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsigned apps will be terminated despite iOS being jailbroken. The fix is, you can still sign with a certificate created by yourself or just fake sign with ldid.

The following link explains it in detail.

[Link](http://mhassan.me/2013/02/15/using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device/252173#252173)

Comment: Good answer, but better to link to existing resources on Stack Overflow.  They tend not to stale out the way pages on external sites do.  There's plenty of discussion of `ldid` here to reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to fix it I followed this guide, making sure to follow the steps at the bottom (to add SHA1 Hashes, and to put it in my device.) From [this guide.](http://www.sysrage.net/guides/ios-programming/building-and-running-ios-applications-without-a-paid-developer-license/)

Add Required SHA1 Hashes To Application Binary:

- In the Xcode Project Navigator, expand the section "Products".
- Right-click the application binary (HelloWorld.app) and select "Show In Finder".
- Copy the application binary to the desktop.
- Open Terminal on the OSX system where the application was built.
- Add the SHA1 hashes to the application binary:

  `# cd ~/Desktop/`
  `# ldid -S HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld`