# iOS In House Distribution with iOS Enterprise program and external developer

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

if external developer is developing the app for one client that is going to distribute the app in house, how should the developer export the app, so that the client can than distribute it in house.

Does developer need private key of In House Distribution certificate of the client? Are there other solutions to export the app for the client without getting the private key of In House Dist. certificate?

**Solution**

I came out with following solution:

- get admin rights for iOS Enterprise program
- create new certificate (or get the private key from team agent) (thanks to Z.pyyyy)
- configure XCode to allow "don't sign code" like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396299/generating-an-unsigned-ipa-ios-application)
- in project and targets build settings use "don't sign code" for signing and automatic for provisioning profiles (it will take the provisioning profile for your team)
- select right team
- archive your project
- use export for enterprise distribution (this creates ipa file)
- distribute the ipa file

Comment: does the developer get any access to that enterprise program ?

Comment: yes the developer has full access, as admin

Comment: Have you considered distributing the app via TestFlight and add all client test-users as external testers, either via their developer account or via his?

Comment: thats not the solution because every beta lasts for 30 days

Comment: Another way for the developer is to get all UDIDs that will use the app and distribute via Ad-Hoc? Additional option is to re-sign the exported app.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, as an external developer, you don't need any of those certificate or signing identity stuff.

You can generate an unsigned ipa iOS application, send the unsigned ipa file to your client so that they can resign the application as they like.

You can refer to the following links:

[Generating an unsigned IPA iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396299/generating-an-unsigned-ipa-ios-application)

and

[How to Re-sign an iOS App from External Developers](http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/)