# How to create .xcarchive

Tags: provisioning-profile, xctool, xcarchive

How can I create `.xcarchive` without any signing? (I'll sign it later)

I've tried so far this:

```
xctool -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos -workspace "/users/myUser/path/to/workspace/myWorkspace.xcworkspace" -scheme myScheme clean archive -archivePath "/users/myUser/path/to/archive/myArchive.xcarchive"
```

This command failed with this error:

`Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.`

But I only wanted `.xcarchive` without any `provision profile`.

Any help will be thankful!

Comment: Have you tried the instructions here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25396370/3708242